# Text Normalization

Tags: java

I have written some code to normalize some sentences in a document.
The requirement is that :
Only one space between words.

- Only one space after comma (,), dot (.) and colon (:). First character of word after dot is in Uppercase and other
  words are in lower case.
- There are no spaces before and after sentence or word phrases in quotes (“”).
- First character of word in first line is in Uppercase.
- There are no blank line between lines
- There are no space between comma or dot and word in front of it.
- Must have dot at the end of text.
  I feel like my script is kind of long and not really correct, any ideas to minimize my code? Thanks you for reading!!!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
//
        String text = "as you can see , detecting whether a string is normalized can be quite efficient . a lot of the cost of normalizing in the \" second row  \" is for the initialization of buffers. The cost of which is amortized when one is processing larger strings.\n" +
"    as it turns out, these buffers are rarely needed, so we may change the implementation at some point to speed up the common case for small strings even further";
        System.out.println(convert(text));
    }

    static String convert(String text) {
        text = text.replaceAll("[\\s&&[^\\n]]+", " ").replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", ", ").replaceAll("\\s*\\.[\\s&&[^\n]]*", ", ").
                replaceAll("\\s*:\\s*", ": ").replaceAll("\\n+", "\n").replaceAll("^\n|\n$", "");
        String temp = "";
        String []str = text.split("\\.");
            for (String string : str) {              
                temp += StringUtils.capitalize(string) + ".";
        } 
        text = temp;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\")(.+)(\")");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);      
        if (matcher.find()){
            text = text.replace(matcher.group(2), matcher.group(2).trim());
        }                  
        return text;  
    }
}
```

Comment: For testing correctness: do not look to others! Think up the different requirements, and then write one or more for each case you can think of.

Comment: If anything, I would minimize it less:  there is no benefit to chaining all those `replaceAll` calls.  Putting each call on a separate line would make them vastly easier to read.  And since you’re asking Stack Overflow for help, it is in your best interest to present code that is easy to read.